# In android crashes why is the pc register different from the backtrace pc values?

Tags: android, crash

My expectation is that the pc register would equal the pc value of frame 0 within the backtrace, but actually they are different (0000007cba01b640 vs 0000000000042f89). Why is that?

Example trace:

```
Build fingerprint: 'google/foo/bar:10/123.456/78910:user/release-keys'
ABI: 'arm64'
Timestamp: 2020-02-16 11:16:31+0100
pid: 8288, tid: 8288, name: com.example.testapp  >>> com.example.testapp <<<
uid: 1010332
signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x0
Cause: null pointer dereference
    x0  0000007da81396c0  x1  0000007fc91522d4  x2  0000000000000001  x3  000000000000206e
    x4  0000007da8087000  x5  0000007fc9152310  x6  0000007d209c6c68  x7  0000007da8087000
    x8  0000000000000000  x9  0000007cba01b660  x10 0000000000430000  x11 0000007d80000000
    x12 0000000000000060  x13 0000000023fafc10  x14 0000000000000006  x15 ffffffffffffffff
    x16 0000007cba01b618  x17 0000007da44c88c0  x18 0000007da943c000  x19 0000007da8087000
    x20 0000000000000000  x21 0000007da8087000  x22 0000007fc9152540  x23 0000007d17982d6b
    x24 0000000000000004  x25 0000007da823c020  x26 0000007da80870b0  x27 0000000000000001
    x28 0000007fc91522d0  x29 0000007fc91522a0
    sp  0000007fc9152290  lr  0000007d22d4e354  pc  0000007cba01b640

backtrace:
  #00  pc 0000000000042f89  /data/app/com.example.testapp/lib/arm64/libexample.so (com::example::Crasher::crash() const)
  #01  pc 0000000000000640  /data/app/com.example.testapp/lib/arm64/libexample.so (com::example::runCrashThread())
  #02  pc 0000000000065a3b  /system/lib/libc.so (__pthread_start(void*))
  #03  pc 000000000001e4fd  /system/lib/libc.so (__start_thread)
```

Comment: isn't that the offset from the base address of the module?

Comment: Does that mean 0000007cba01b640 minus 0000000000042f89 is the base address of the module?